# QPushButton with menu - drop from right side

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qpushbutton, qmenu

I have a long `QPushButton` (well, a subclass of one) with a menu attached. The drop-down menu indicator is on the right side of the button, but when pressed the menu drops down from the bottom-left corner. This seems to me like it will be clunky and unintuitive for my users.

[image: Left-side drop down menu]

I've looked through the `QPushButton` source code, and tried:

```
this->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft);
```

which did move the menu to the right side, but it broke the button as it also moved the indicator to the left side and made the menus backwards.

[image]

Is there another way to make the menu drop from the right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by installing an event filter on the menu used for the `QPushButton` which moves it when shown.

```
class rightSideMenuFilter : public QObject
{
public:

    bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent *event)
    {
        QPushButton* parentButton = dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(obj->parent());
        if (!parentButton)
            return false;

        QMenu* menu = dynamic_cast<QMenu*>(obj);
        if (!menu)
            return false;

        if (event->type() == QEvent::Show && obj == parentButton->menu())
        {
            QPoint pos = menu->pos();
            qDebug() << "pos" << pos;

            pos.setX(pos.x() + parentButton->width() - menu->width());
            parentButton->menu()->move(pos);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```